# Detect how much the user has scrolled within an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, overflow

I'm building a web app for which I disable the bounce back effect of OS X and iOS, but still need the user to be able to scroll.

So I ended up using this CSS trick to achieve that:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

It works just fine (although not quite as smoothly as without the trick — any suggestions?). Given that I disable the scroll on the html, I know that I've got to bind the .scroll() to the body:

```
$('body').scroll(function() {
    doSomething();
});
```

But the thing is, I need to detect how much the user has scrolled **within** the body element, and I can't seem to figure out how to do just that.

```
var doSomething = function(){  
    var scrollTop = $('body').offset().top; // returns 0.
    var scrollTop = $('body').scrollTop(); // returns 0 as well. 
};
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: My solution below should work, even though it got downvoted. I'm not sure the other poster understood all of the details of the question.

Answer (score -1):

**Easiest solution:**

The easiest thing to do is just to check the position of the top element inside the body:

[Here's the codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mnIbo/)

```
$(function(){
    $('body').scroll(function(){
        // Substitute your first element for 'header.main'
        console.log( $('header.main').position().top ); 
    });
});
```

**Another method:**

Or you can add a wrapper element like below:

I was able to get a correct offset by adding another element wrapper inside the body and checking the position of that.

[Here's the codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rlAvE/)

```
<body>
  <div id="offset">
    <!-- all of your content in the "offset" wrapper -->
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').scroll(function(){
        console.log( $('#offset').position().top );
    });
});
```

**Update:** I tested this in OSX, and it looks like this does indeed suppress the bounce effect AND give the correct scroll offset number.

Comment: There is a scrollbar ... You could just changed `overflow:hidden;` to `auto` for the same effect. THIS is an invalid answer, because OP wanted to use `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` which you dodge with this new container.

Comment: @Nico O - I'm not sure OP was trying to get rid of the scrollbar. I assume there will be content inside the body, and that will add a scrollbar. I just added a wrapper around it. The biggest trouble for these tests is that I don't think the OSX bounce scroll is active inside iFrames (on codepen and jsfiddle). I guess OP will have to test.

Comment: if OP did not wanted scrollbars, he could have just have done this: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/jNe52/4/  and that was exactly the point of my answer. You just moved this down one level in the dom Tree. For what?

Comment: what ever. I'll remove my answer and comment. I sticked with the CSS given by OP. When he does not understand, what he have done with Overflow and is wondering why the scrolling does not work, I can not help him.